# getting class cast exception

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

i just want to pass sql query builder query in JPA like

```
        public List<QueryBuilder[]> getQueryBuilder(String query) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            Query q = em.createNativeQuery(query);
            List<QueryBuilder[]> queryBuilderList = (List<QueryBuilder[]>) q.getResultList();
            return queryBuilderList;

        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
```

the query

```
SELECT p.*,c.*,e.*,pmh.*,rk.* 
FROM patient p, case1 c, episode e, personal_medical_history pmh, reproductive_history rh 
WHERE c.Clinical_Stage = 'IA2' 
AND c.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id 
AND e.Case_Id = c.Case_Id 
AND pmh.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id 
AND rh.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id 
GROUP BY p.patient_Id
```

and on service i do somthing like

```
 List<QueryBuilder[]> list = builderJpaController.getQueryBuilder(query);
       for (QueryBuilder[] queryBuilders : list) {
        for (QueryBuilder queryBuilder : queryBuilders) {
            System.out.println("queryBuilder Value "+queryBuilder.getRace());
        }
    }
```

but i'm getting class cast exception by doing above code please help
below is the exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lcom.medikm.entity.QueryBuilder;
    at com.medikm.servlet.QueryBuilderServlet.getQueryJson(QueryBuilderServlet.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

Comment: where are you getting this exception and what is the exact error message?

Comment: Please, add the full stack trace.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lcom.medikm.entity.QueryBuilder;
        at com.medikm.servlet.QueryBuilderServlet.getQueryJson(QueryBuilderServlet.java:76)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

Comment: well, not every Object is an instance of QueryBuilder. Check line 76 in your class QueryBuilderServlet

Comment: @MonuMittal The full stack trace, please. And  `query` too.

Comment: Where is `QueryBuilderServlet.getQueryJson`?

Comment: SELECT p.*,c.*,e.*,pmh.*,rk.*
FROM patient p, case1 c, episode e, personal_medical_history pmh, reproductive_history rh
WHERE c.Clinical_Stage = 'IA2'
 AND c.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id
 AND e.Case_Id = c.Case_Id
 AND pmh.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id
 AND rh.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id
 GROUP BY p.patient_Id

Comment: @MonuMittal Add it to the question, please. :)

Comment: i unable to add this to question it gives me an error

Comment: You select "p.*,c.*,e.*,pmh.*,rk.*" and expect that to magically be returned as a QueryBuilder object?! and you haven't even posted what that class is. Perhaps read a JPA tutorial about result classes, and read JDK javadocs about what a ClassCastException is

Answer (score 0):

The problematic line is:

```
List<QueryBuilder[]> queryBuilderList = (List<QueryBuilder[]>) q.getResultList();
```

You are assuming that the untyped list returned by `q.getResultList()` is a list of `QueryBuilder[]`s. Actually it is an `Object[]`. However, this compiles because `q.getResultList()` has a raw return type, so the compiler can't tell that this is unsafe.

Then, when consuming the elements of the list, you attempt to cast an `Object[]` to a `QueryBuilder[]` - which can't be done.

It is very unlikely that the elements of rows returned by a query would themselves be `QueryBuilder` instances - they are much more likely to be "plain old" values, like Strings, numbers etc.

(I say "very unlikely" because I'm not familiar with JPA - I am just going off what I expect a persistence API to do)

You need to rethink your expectations of what you are trying to do here.

---

Note that even if the elements of the `Object[]` were instances of `QueryBuilder`, you can't cast a `Superclass[]` reference to a `Subclass[]` reference - there is no superclass/subclass relationship between array types.

You need to explicitly cast each of the individual elements:

```
Subclass[] castArray(Superclass[] arr) {
  Subclass[] subclassArr = new Subclass[arr.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    subclassArr[i] = (Subclass) arr[i];
  }
  return subclassArr;
}
```

Comment: as you say i did `public List<Object[]> getQueryBuilder(String query) {
         EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
         try {
             Query q = em.createNativeQuery(query);
             List<Object[]> queryBuilderList = (List<Object[]>) q.getResultList();
             return queryBuilderList;
             
         } finally {
             em.close();
         }
     }`

Comment: but please tell how can i add this into a list

Comment: It is a list already. You can simplay iterate over it and return the results. See http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-native-queries/.